# OkHTTPClient hangs on Multipart request

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm running OkHTTP3 on Android Lollipop and I have the following static method to upload an image in a multipart form request:

```
public static void uploadImage(Context context, String imageTitle, Uri imageUri, CallbackReceiver callbackReceiver) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(imageUri));
    String filePath = imageUri.toString();
    String fileName = imageUri.getLastPathSegment();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(type);
    RequestBody rb = RequestBody.create(mediaType, file);
    requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image", fileName, rb)
                .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(RequestConstants.POST_IMAGE)
                .addHeader(
                        RequestConstants.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                        RequestConstants.HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX +
                                AccessToken.get())
                .addHeader(
                        RequestConstants.HTTP_HEADER_ACCEPT,
                        RequestConstants.HTTP_APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
    run(request, callbackReceiver);
```

The RequestConstants are String values that work in other GET and POST requests.

The run method implementation:

```
private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

private static void run(Request request, final CallbackReceiver callbackReceiver) {
    try {
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                callbackReceiver.onSuccess(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                callbackReceiver.onFailure(e);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("OkHttpClient", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the request, I never receive an answer - neither the onSuccess nor the onFailure callbacks are executed.

In Logcat I can see that there are several 'suspending all threads', which could indicate a performance issue, although I am testing with a very small image (~250kB).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I've been sending requests over HTTPS, after using HTTP I've been getting responses with timeouts. This was due to the fact that the default write timeout for OkHTTPClient was too low. After increasing the write timeout I've managed to get this code to work. However, very large images still cause a timeout that doesn't trigger any callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a while ago. To make sure it's not left unanswered: I increased the timeout on the client. I was unable to find the piece of code that fixed it.